# Not able to Get the session values in class library

Tags: asp.net

This is the my first post and i am very excited to speak with you all experts and learn .

I have added objects to the session state in an aspx page which is using an object datasource.I want to  get the session value in the class library which is used by the object datasource.

code in class library

```
selectedrelease = HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedbuild"].ToString();
```

code in aspx page

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedbuild"] = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
```

However i am not able to get the session value in class library
Please help
Many Thanks for the help in advance 
Rahul

Comment: Can you give more information about when this code is called in relation to the page. Is it executed as an `HttpModule`, on `PageInit`, `PageLoad`, `PreRender` etc?

Comment: i an using an object datasource in the aspx page and i am trying to use the session variable in a function in a class library, and this function is used by the select method property of the objectdatasource

Comment: In your aspx page do you actually create the session variable e.g.  HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("selectedbuild", Value/Object)? If not created properly you'll not be able to reference it's value. Does the class library always find it null?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good idea is to structure your code so that you work with these values as parameters passed from one context to the other. Maybe right now you read your data from the session state but tomorrow you'll have to read it from the query string or some control on a page. Maybe you'll even find another use for the same piece of code that fills the datasource but you'll be stuck because it's not flexible enough.

So what I suggest is to not attempt to read that value directly from some specific source but expect it as a parameter.

Specific to your current issue, it's normal that you can only access the Session state from the context of the web application itself, not from a distinct library.

Comment: Can you please explain how can i use sessionparamter in this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the values from the session which you need in your library as parameters. Separating gui and logic is always a good idea.